# Use Ubuntu Environment Variables in Gradle Properties File

Tags: java, ubuntu, gradle, jetty

I have an Environment Variable on an Ubuntu server, `SDB_DOMAIN`, that I'm trying to pass to this gradle properties file:

https://github.com/Netflix/SimianArmy/blob/master/src/main/resources/janitor.properties#L20

What's the syntax to pull environment variables into a properties file like this?  I've tried a couple different ways, one example being: `simianarmy.janitor.snapshots.ownerId = System.getenv("SIMIAN_OWNER_ID")` but that just returns the literal value when I start the jetty server with`gradlew jettRun` and watch the logs.

```
19:55:53.957 [main] INFO  c.n.s.basic.BasicSimianArmyContext - using standard     class for simianarmy.client.recorder.class
19:55:54.060 [main] INFO  c.n.simianarmy.aws.SimpleDBRecorder - Creating SimpleDB domain: "System.getenv(SDB_DOMAIN)"
19:55:54.122 [main] WARN  c.n.simianarmy.aws.SimpleDBRecorder - Error while trying to auto-create SimpleDB domain
com.amazonaws.services.simpledb.model.InvalidParameterValueException: Value ("System.getenv(SDB_DOMAIN)") for parameter DomainName is invalid. (Service: AmazonSimpleDB; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: 4aabdeb2-68a5-0f49-dacd-17c96f375793)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I did. I Wanted my Spring-Boot Application to show me $HOME variable.

My **application.properties** file:

`variable.home = #{ systemEnvironment['HOME'] }`

Class that is using it:

```
@Component
public class SomeName implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Value("${variable.home}" )
            String home;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(home);
    }

    public String getHome() {
        return home;
    }

    public void setHome(String home) {
        this.home = home;
    }
}
```

**Spring boot starting log**:

```
2015-12-10 17:46:07.622  INFO 5710 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2015-12-10 17:46:07.652  INFO 5710 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
/home/dogbert
2015-12-10 17:46:07.655  INFO 5710 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication              : Started DemoApplication in 1.431 seconds (JVM running for 1.614)
```

and **echo $HOME**:

```
dogbert@borsuk:~$ echo $HOME
/home/dogbert
dogbert@borsuk:~$
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: hey thanks, this should work nicely for what I'm looking to do!